# Chart image in email from Google spreadsheet with google-apps-script returns white image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sending a report every night to my own gmail address. Suddenly since a week or so the image of the chart has turned blank. There is only one chart.

```
function sendReport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("monthData");
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  if(charts.length > 0) {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("reportTemplate");
    template.date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MM-y");
    var areaBlob = charts[0].getBlob().getAs('image/png').setName("areaBlob");
    MailApp.sendEmail({ to:"olivier.dejonge@gmail.com",
                        subject: "Trend uren declarabel",
                        htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent(),
                        inlineImages: {
                          chart: areaBlob
                        }
                      });
  }else {
    Browser.msgBox("Kon report niet verzenden omdat ik chart niet kon vinden");
  }
}
```

Code.gs

```
<html>
  <h1>Dagelijkse Trend Declarabele uren: <?= date ?></h1>
  <p>
    <img src="cid:chart" />
  </p>
</html>
```

reportTemplate.html

[image]

in spreadsheet it looks fine

[image]

in email it's not there!?

**Update**

When I update the data with function "updateUren" of the spreadsheet the chart stays blank too.

```
function updateUren()
{
  var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var startYear = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("settings").getRange(2,1,1,1).getValue();
  var endYear = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("settings").getRange(2,2,1,1).getValue();
  var calendars = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("settings").getRange(2,3,1,1).getValue().split("/");
  var hourPriceArr = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("settings").getRange(2,4,1,1).getValue().split("/");
  var myPrice = hourPriceArr[0].split(",");
  var myHourPrice = [];
  for(var i=0 ; i < myPrice.length; i++) {
    var orgPrice = myPrice[i].split(":");
    myHourPrice.push(orgPrice)
  }
  var vasilesPrice = hourPriceArr[1].split(",");
  var vasileHourPrice = [];
  for(var i=0 ; i < vasilesPrice.length ; i++) {
    vasileHourPrice.push(vasilesPrice[i].split(":"))
  }
  var hourHash = [{hourPrice:myHourPrice, hirePrice:[]}, {hourPrice:myHourPrice, hirePrice:vasileHourPrice}]

  var startDate = new Date();
  var details=[]; 

  for(var i in calendars)
  {
    startDate = collectEvents_(details, calendars[i], startYear, endYear, startDate, hourHash[i].hourPrice, hourHash[i].hirePrice);
  }

  /*month*/
  var monthDetails = getMonthDetails_(details); 

  sheet = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("monthData");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:E")
  range.clear();
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, monthDetails.length, 5).setValues(monthDetails);


  /*all*/
  details.unshift(["title", "date", "start", "end", "duration", "profit"]);
  sheet = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("data");
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, details.length, 6).setValues(details);
}
```

It's only when I refresh the page in the browser that the chart shows it's graph again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank image is due to a sharing permissions issue. Change the share settings of the spreadsheet to "Anyone who has the link can view" and the chart will then be exportable from your script.

Comment: You  made my day, thanks! It's a pity I have to make it 'semi public', but I take that for granted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this would have stopped working, but you might want to try dropping the "getBlob()" part and see if that helps. Documentation suggests the below code should work.

```
var areaBlob = charts[0].getAs('image/png').setName("areaBlob");
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getAs(String)