# How to insert a Google Spreadsheet embedded chart in a Google Sites via Google Script?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I have a Google Script which creates embedded charts in various sheets in a Spreadsheet.
Once created those charts I have to display them on a Google Site.
Is there a way using Google Script (I need this to be automatic) to get those embedded charts and show them on a Google Site web page?

I tried this code:

```
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var blob = chart.getBlob().setContentType('image/jpeg');
  var bytes = blob.getBytes();
  var base64String = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
  var site = SitesApp.getSite('aperturelabs.it', 'testkpi');
  var page = site.getChildByName('home');
  var html = '<img src="data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + base64String + '"/>';
  Logger.log(html);
  page.setHtmlContent(html);
```

The resulting  tag is:

```
<img src="javascript:void(0);" alt="img name">
```

But Logger logs base64 string correctly.

This is the code I use to create charts:

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .addRange(sheet.getRange(newRow, newColumn, rows, columns))
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
  .setPosition(7, 7, 0, 0)
  .setOption('title', title)
  .setOption('series',series)
  .build();
sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104760/chart-image-in-email-from-google-spreadsheet-with-google-apps-script-returns-whi. Change the share settings on the sheet to anyone with a link can view and then try?

Comment: It's shared to anyone with link already.
I discovered that Base64 images are not supported by Google Sites: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/3GhnAUtxJFA

I'm searching if a chart may be embedde in other ways; still, no luck...

Comment: What about google visualization? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. Thanks everyone for helping!
I created a new page from a template on Sites everytime a user inputs data in the Spreadsheet (if not already present) then, from Sites, i used a `google.visualization.Query` to query data and build a new chart within a gadget.