# How to add an existing chart in sheets while sending an email

Tags: google-apps-script

I want a Line chart from my spreadsheet to appear in the email.

```
function sendEmails() { 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Agent Report - Monthly") 
    var startRow = 3; // First row of data to process since there is a header row 
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Agent Report - Monthly").getRange("D3");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

    var chartImg = Charts.newLineChart.setRange(12, 8) //This Throws an error
    var subject = "Agent Report - Monthly"; // This is the subject of the email  
    var greeting_text = 'Hey Please find the below Report '+'</b><br><br>';
    var text = greeting_text;
    text+=SheetConverter.convertRange2html(sheet.getRange(startRow, 3 ,10,8));
    text+='<br>';
    var options = {
        htmlBody: text,
        noReply:true
    };
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "xxx@der.com",
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: options,
        inlineImages: {
            chartImg: chartImage,
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to add the chart to the variable `ChartImg` in line 7, it throws an exception.

Comment: Hi Ridhima, are you trying to get the chart image, as if it was a screenshot and add it to the email body? or are you trying to create the chart in the file and then send the file in the email? Also, what is the error you get?

Comment: I just want to add the chart as an image in the email, the chart is already in sheets

Comment: The error message may help. Edit your question to include the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you already have the chart created without issue in the spreadsheet, and you only want to get it as an image. To do this you need a reference to the chart in the sheet, and then use the `getAs()` method on the chart's blob, it would look something like this for you:

```
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; // assuming you only have that chart, this is just to get the chart's reference.
var options = {
    htmlBody: "<img src='cid:chart' style='width:24px; height:16px;'/>",
    noReply:true
};

var chartImg = chart.getBlob().getAs('image/png').setName("areaBlob");

// Then you would add it in the body of the email as an attachment
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "xxx@der.com",
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: options,
    inlineImages: {
        chart: chartImg,
    }
});
```

In the following link you can find a more in depth explanation and example: [Chart image in email from Google spreadsheet with google-apps-script returns white image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104760/chart-image-in-email-from-google-spreadsheet-with-google-apps-script-returns-whi)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the chart comes as an attachment in PDF and not as an image within the email.

Comment: Is the chart showing in the PDF? or is it blank in the email?

Comment: I see what was missing, the htmlBody is missing the inline image. To fix this, your "options" body needs to be changed to:

  `var options = {htmlBody: "<img src='cid:chart' style='width:24px; height:16px;'/>",noReply:true};`

Please let me know if this attaches the image to the email correctly, it should appear in the body of the message

Comment: On my previous comment I set the sizes to 24x16 pixels, this is really small, I think if you do 100x100 it should be much better for what you need.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!